# Two site with two different language in WP

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, multisite

please help !

We have developed two website for one same organization (two different businesses) which both are in English language.

Now the requirement is, it should be converted to WordPress and  should be like as follow.

www.company.com (Home page will have switch for both sub sites)
1. business1.com (arabic/english) 
2. business2.com (arabic/english)

How can i do this in Wordpress? how to categorize both site in one WP and again how can I make two languages in each site.

I am sorry we are not live yet to show anything, working on local host

Answer (score 0):

Try multi language plugin or wp localization.

That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use he WordPress Multilingual Plugin from http://wpml.org/, i had used it and it is really good.